# Statistics from workbook

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a mutable sheet workbook. I have several people entering their work into it. I need to pull statistics from entries by date and assigned to a person by name. I have pulled information by date but need to further break it down by assigned person’s name. Any help?

```
Order number    Order Date  Filled Date Shipped Date    sales Person
2013-001        1/23/2013   1/23/2013   1/26/2013       Bill
2013-002        2/12/2013   2/13/2013   2/15/2013       Bill
2013-003        3/12/2013   3/12/2013   3/14/2013       Tom
2013-004        4/12/2013   4/13/2013   4/20/2013       Tim
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a PivotTable, maybe something like this:

[image: SO19692318 example]

but you have option on which date or dates to choose and how to organise the layout.